# Pure Python 3.6.3 - finding the difference in degrees between 2 3d vectors

Tags: python, 3d, turtle-graphics, normals

For some ungodly reason I'm trying to make a program to display wireframe graphics in pure python 3.6.3 with the turtle library. I've got to the point where I would like to skip drawing unnecessary tris for optimisation purposes. Unnecessary tris meaning tris that should be obscured by other parts of the model - ie, the normal facing away from the 3d camera.

The model data that the program is working with is just a huge 3d array with the following formatting for each tri.

```
[[Vert],[Vert],[Vert],[Normal]]
```

My current version of the code only has one model made for it (a cube) and looks like this:

```
from turtle import *

Cube = [[[-50,50,-50],[-50,50,50,],[50,50,50],[0,1,0]],
        [[-50,50,-50],[50,50,50,],[50,50,-50],[0,1,0]],
        [[-50,50,-50],[-50,50,50],[-50,-50,50],[1,0,0]],
        [[-50,50,-50],[-50,-50,-50],[-50,-50,50],[1,0,0]],
        [[-50,50,50],[50,50,50],[50,-50,50],[0,0,1]],
        [[-50,50,50],[50,-50,50],[-50,50,50],[0,0,1]],
        [[-50,-50,-50],[-50,-50,50,],[50,-50,50],[0,-1,0]],
        [[-50,-50,-50],[50,-50,50,],[50,-50,-50],[0,-1,0]],
        [[50,50,-50],[50,50,50],[50,-50,50],[-1,0,0]],
        [[50,50,-50],[50,-50,-50],[50,-50,50],[-1,0,0]],
        [[-50,50,-50],[50,50,-50],[50,-50,-50],[0,0,-1]],
        [[-50,50,-50],[50,-50,-50],[-50,50,-50],[0,0,-1]]]

CamVector = [0,1,0]

def DrawModel(Model):
    for i in range(0,len(Model)):
        goto(Model[i][0][0],Model[i][0][1])
        pd()
        goto(Model[i][1][0],Model[i][1][1])
        goto(Model[i][2][0],Model[i][2][1])
        goto(Model[i][0][0],Model[i][0][1])
        pu()

Model = Cube
DrawModel(Model)
```

But I would like to compare each tri's normal to the CamVector so the code ends up looking like this:

```
def DrawModel(Model):
    for i in range(0,len(Model)):
        AngleAwayFromCamera = *Math voodoo*
        if AngleAwayFromCamera <= 90:
            *draw tri*
```

If anyone has any idea on how to help that could be explained to someone with with a walnut-sized brain like myself that would be great. I've looked at a lot of documentation but most has flown right over my head - Probably because I failed GCSE maths.

Comment: To summarise, do you want to be able to solve the general problem of finding the angle between two vectors, in the specific case of each tri's normal vector and the camera vector?

Comment: Pretty much exactly that just presented in a way a 3 year old could get.

Comment: the scalar/dot product of vectors divided by lenghts of the vectors is equal to cosine of the angle

Comment: Might sound stupid but isn't a vector just a direction? how can it have a length?

Comment: @ReesK A vector describes how to get to a point from another point. To do that, you need to know which direction you're going, as well as how far to go.

Answer (score 1):

Without going too much into the mathematical details, there's something called a *dot product* in mathematics:

[image]

Basically, it's a way of combining two vectors (call them **a** and **b**) to get a single number. This number is equal to the magnitude of **a**, multiplied by the magnitude of **b**, multiplied by the cosine of the angle between them (which we can call θ).

Thanks to this equation, by shifting things around, we can eventually get to what we want, which is θ.

Say we have **a**: `[1, 2, 3]` and **b**: `[4, 5, 6]`. We can calculate their magnitudes by squaring their elements and taking the square root of the sum. Therefore, the magnitude of **a** is `(1 ** 2 + 2 ** 2 + 3 ** 2) ** 0.5 = 14 ** 0.5`, and that of **b** is `(4 ** 2 + 5 ** 2 + 6 ** 2) ** 0.5 = 77 ** 0.5`.

Multiplying them together gives us `1078 ** 0.5`. Therefore, the dot product is equal to `(1078 ** 0.5) * cos θ`.

It turns out that the dot product can be calculated by multiplying corresponding elements of two vectors together and summing the result. So, for **a** and **b** above, the dot product is `1 * 4 + 2 * 5 + 3 * 6 = 32`.

Given these two different (but equal) expressions of the dot product, we can equate them to solve for θ, as follows (arccos is the function that turns cos θ into θ):

```
(1078 ** 0.5) * cos θ = 32
cos θ = 32 / (1078 ** 0.5)
θ = arccos(32 / (1078 ** 0.5))
θ ≈ 12.93 (in degrees)
```

Now, all that is left is to implement this in code:

```
from numpy import arccos

def angle_between_vectors(v1, v2):
    def magnitude(v):
        return sum(e ** 2 for e in v) ** 0.5

    dot_product = sum(e1 * e2 for e1, e2 in zip(v1, v2))
    magnitudes = magnitude(v1) * magnitude(v2)
    angle = arccos(dot_product / magnitudes)
    return angle
```

Applying this function to **a** and **b** above and converting from radians to degrees (divide by π and multiply by 180) gives us 12.93, as expected.